# Interactive force directed graph

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am working on a force directed layout of nodes and edges.In my graph each node belong to a category.There are 3 kinds of nodes.
1.Organization 2.Person 3.Country

So each person can belong to an Organization or country.So there are edges are like

```
person-->Organization  
person-->Country  
person-->person  
Country --> Organization and so on....
```

The forced layout is ready. But my new requirement is if there is check box for each category and if I click on a category check box then I should not see those nodes belonging to that category.

So if click on Organization check box all organization nodes should disappear and the edges of that nodes should extend themselves.

Supposedly

```
Person 1-->organization 1-->Person 2
```

if click on organization check box the graph should reorganize itself like...

```
Person 1-->Person 2  

organization 1-->country 1-->organization 2
```

and clicking on country check box it should be like

```
organization 1-->organization 2
```

Is there any interactive forced layout as such to implement this. Any links and ideas are helpful.My forced layout is similar to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045.

My example JSON format is like below

```
{
    "edges": [
    {
        "label": "person -> org",
        "source": 37,
        "target": 52,
        "id": "154",
        "size": 4
    },
    {
        "label": "country -> org",
        "source": 24,
        "target": 74,
        "id": "29",
        "size": 1
    }
],
    "nodes": [
    {
        "label": "Algeria",
        "id": "10009",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "country"
        },
        "size": 3.9024388790130615
    },
    {
        "label": "Foundation INTISAAR",
        "id": "5014",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "organization"
        },
        "size": 12.609755516052246
    },
    {
        "label": "Abdul rah man",
        "id": "5014",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "person"
        },
        "size": 5.609755516052246
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795)?

Comment: Should be kind of easy to do what you want. Please give us some code my friend. Is http://arda-maps.org/familytree/ what goes in the direction you basically want? Or do you want a real menu when clicking on a node? At least show us a picture. That would really help.

Comment: check out http://www.jsfiddle.net/3m03uh2h/8 . If I click on organization radio button all nodes belonging to organization class should be removed(links connected to org1 also should be removed) and new links will be added among person, country nodes. Checkout the code in the fiddle. apparently I think we should do splice() and push() between the nodes and links to get the effect.